# Set a read only property defined in a interface within a concrete class

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, interface

I have an interface with a read only property

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

and a concrete class...

```
public class Person : IPerson
{

    public Person()
    {
        Name = "Person";
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
}
```

I want Name to be read only externally to this class, but how do I set it from within the concrete class?

Error: Person.Name cannot be assigned to.

How do I set the value of this property from within Person class?

Comment: I now realize that I could simply of excluded the return Name; bit and just had the get;

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with the interface, you're just declaring the property incorrectly.  In C# 6, you can create a read-only property like this:

```
public class Person : IPerson
{
    public Person()
    {
        Name = "Person";
    }

    public string Name { get; }
}
```

In earlier versions, you can use a read-only backing field which you can set:

```
public class Person : IPerson
{
    private readonly string _name;

    public Person()
    {
        _name = "Person";
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
    }
}
```

Note that the interface only requires the property has a getter, the implementation doesn't have to be read-only. You could add a setter if you had reason to modify the value:

```
public class Person : IPerson
{
    public Person()
    {
        Name = "Person";
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The setter could be private if you only needed to be able to change the value from within the class.

Comment: This will only work when the property is really supposed to be read-only, though. It's not clear from the OP's description if he wants to change the value later, from within the `Person` class.

Comment: Thanks - I understand how this works now. I don't need to change the Name once written (in this example), but if I did - then I would use accessors

Answer (score 6):

You can use a private property to hold the value.

```
public class Person : IPerson
{
    private string _name;
    public Person()
    {
        _name = "Person";
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Right now, you're trying to read the property by reading the property. Needless to say, this will result in an endless loop. Instead, you either need to use full-blown auto-properties, or a manual backing field.

```
public class Person : IPerson
{
    public Person()
    {
        Name = "Person";
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You simply have a private setter (pre c#6):

```
public class Person : IPerson
{

    public Person()
    {
        Name = "Person";
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using [accessors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287786(v=vs.71).aspx):

```
private string _name;

public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return _name;
    }
}
```

You can then set the value of `_name` inside any method or the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

> *I want Name to be read only externally to this class, but how do I set it from within the concrete class*

First of all, let's realize that: **an interface only describes a set of `public` requirements**; it does not prevent us from implementing *other* public members, **nor does it limit our ability to create private members**.

Therefore, to make a property writeable from inside the class but read-only elsewhere, we can declare the `set` method with `private` scope:

```
public class Person : IPerson
{
    // Name is read-only outside the class, but can be set internally
    public string Name { get; private set; } = "DefaultName";

    public Person() { }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        // Potentially do some validation before setting the name
        if (!IsValidName(name)) 
            throw new ArgumentException("Name cannot be null, empty, or whitespace.");

        Name = name;
    }

    private bool IsValidName(string name)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(name);
    }

    // Continued below...
```

And if we want to, we can give access to the private setter through a method. This is often done in order to make the renaming of a person very intentional (for example, it prevents accidental assignments when a comparison was intended). The client will get a design-time error from the compiler if they try `person.Name = "Foo";` but they *can* write `person.RenameAs("Foo");`

```
    public void RenameAs(string newName)
    {
        // Potentially do some validation before setting the name
        if (IsValidName(newName)) Name = newName;
    }
}
```